# Show that the form $w$ is closed but not exact

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-forms

Let $$w~=~\dfrac{-y}{x^2+y^2}dx+\dfrac{x}{x^2+y^2}dy, \qquad (x,y)~\in\mathbb{R}^2\backslash \{(0,0)\}.$$

Showing that $w$ is closed is easy. Just calculate $dw$ and you'll get 0.

But how do I show that $w$ is not exact?

In other words, I need to prove that there is no form $\lambda$ such that $w=d \lambda$

Should I assume that $w=d \lambda$ and try to get to a contradiction?

Comment: This is a very common example, try googling it or look it up here on stack exchange

Comment: Hint: Find a closed curve on which the integral isn't zero.

Comment: @Ted I was about to write up an answer saying roughly that, but what theorem says that an exact form has zero integral on closed contours? Stokes' theorem doesn't work because the region on which the form is defined misses the origin.

Comment: @Ted Ok I found one,  can't we just exclude the origin?

Comment: @Mario: It is Stokes's Theorem applied on the closed curve (1-manifold with empty boundary, in this case). Calculus courses call this the FTC for line integrals.  Wwbb90: You need a closed curve in $\Bbb R^2-\{0\}$, hopefully an obvious one where you can easily compute that the integral is nonzero.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think that perhaps one of the most illuminating ways to look at this is to transform $w$ to polar coordinates.  Since

$w = -\dfrac{y}{x^2 + y^2}dx + \dfrac{x}{x^2 +y^2}dy, \tag{1}$

with

$x = r\cos \theta, \tag{2}$

$y = r\sin \theta, \tag{3}$

we immediately see that

$r^2 = x^2 + y^2, \tag{4}$

leading to

$w = -\dfrac{\sin \theta}{r} dx + \dfrac{\cos \theta}{r} dy; \tag{5}$

we also have, from (2) and (3), that

$dx = (\cos \theta) dr - r(\sin \theta)d\theta, \tag{6}$

$dy = (\sin \theta) dr + r(\cos \theta)d \theta, \tag{7}$

and plugging (6) and (7) into (5) yields, after a little algebraic maneuvering,

$w = d\theta. \tag{8}$

Of course in performing the above calculations, we need to remember one little *caveat*:  we must stay away from the point $(x, y) = 0$, that is $r = 0$, where in fact $w$ isn't even defined; we are in "point" of fact operating in the punctured plane $\Bbb R^2 \setminus \{ 0 \}$.  And though (8) gives the superficial impression that $w$ is exact, this only *appears* to be the case, since $\theta$ is not in fact definable as a function on $\Bbb R^2 \setminus \{ 0\}$.  This of course may be concluded from the fact that in traversing a circular path centered at the origin the value if $\theta$ will have increased by $2\pi$ when the starting point is first re-visited; we can in fact express this observation in integral form by computing the line integral of $w = d\theta$ around a circle of radius $R$ centered at the origin.  Let then the circle be given parametrically by $c(t) = (R\cos t, R \sin t)$, $0 \le t \le 2 \pi$; we have

$\displaystyle \int_c w = \int_0^{2\pi} d\theta(c(t))(\dot c(t))dt$
$= \displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} d\theta(c(t))((-R\sin t, R\cos t)^T)dt, \tag{9}$

and if we combine (5) and (8) with the definition of $c(t)$ we see that

$d\theta(c(t)) = -\dfrac{\sin t}{R} dx + \dfrac{\cos t}{R} dy, \tag{10}$

and thus

$d\theta(c(t))(\dot c(t)) = \sin^2 t + \cos^2 t = 1, \tag{11}$

and the integral becomes

$\displaystyle \int_c w = \int_0^{2\pi} dt = 2\pi. \tag{12}$

(12) shows that:  i.) $w = d\theta$ is not exact in $\Bbb R^2 \setminus \{ 0 \}$; and ii.)  $\theta$ cannot really be defined as a function on $\Bbb R^2 \setminus \{ 0 \}$, since we obtain multiple values by integrating $d\theta$ over a path such as $c(t)$.  But I guess the main point here is that $w$ is indeed not exact, and this is how it is shown.

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: Sorry, one more question: You say that $\theta$ is not defined on the plane without origin. Now I understand that $\theta$ is not defined at the origin - but why is it not defined if we take away the origin, i.e. on $\mathbb{R}^2-\{0\}$? Thanks

Comment: @exchange:  $\theta$ is not (well) defined *globally* on $\Bbb R^2 - \{{0}\}$  because, as is shown above, in increases by $2\pi$ as we follow any circular path around $0$.  It can be defined *locally* in an region which does not surround $0$.  Indeed, the answer above shows that assuming the function $\theta$ is globally definable leads to a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks. So if we are in polar coordinates $w=d\theta$ but in these coordinates $w$ is not defined globally. But above $w(x,y)$ is globally defined on $\mathbb{R}^2-\{0\}$ in terms of $x$ and $y$. So when going from cartesian to polar coordinates, this global definition is undone by something. Now I wonder why. My idea is that $\mathbb{R}^2-\{0\}\simeq \mathbb{R}\times S^1$ but $S^1$ is not homeomorphic to $[0,2\pi]$ and therefore the change to polar coordinates is not a diffeomorphism, and therefore $d\theta$ is only defined locally up to $(0,2\pi)$. Is that correct? Thanks for your time.

Comment: @exchange:  Not quite.  $w = d\theta$ *is*  globally valid, but its integral--$\theta$--around loops surrounding $0$ isn't--in the original $x$-$y$ plane $\Bbb R^2$.  The fact that $d\theta$ is globally defined but $\theta$ isn't is the reason why $d\theta$ is closed but not  exact.  You might consider the Riemann surface of $\ln z$; polar coordinates are similar, since going around the origin increases $\theta$ by $2\pi$.  Look at polars in exponential form $re^{i\theta} = e^{\ln r}e^{i\theta} = e^{\ln r + i\theta}$.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 9):

The origin of the monster: Complex Analysis. The function
$$z\longmapsto\frac1z$$
is holomorphic in $\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}$ *without* primitive in $\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}$. Integrating along a path that surrounds the zero:
$$\int_{|z|=1}\frac1z\,dz=2\pi i.$$
The field $w$ will appear while doing the calculations in this line integral.

Answer (score 6):

If $w$ is exact, its integral along any contour $C$ should be equal to zero. But, plotting the vector field $\mathbf{E}=(E_x,E_y)$ with
$$E_x=-\frac{y}{x^2+y^2},\qquad E_y=\frac{x}{x^2+y^2},$$
we will get something like this:

[image]

and it is clear that the integral $\int \mathbf{E}\cdot d\mathbf{r}$ along the circles centered at the origin does not vanish.

Comment: you mean exact?

Comment: @Alex oh yes sure, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Let $\alpha :[0,2\pi]\to \mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{0\}$ with $\alpha(t)=(cos(t),sin(t))$. Remark that $\alpha$ is a closed curve (i.e., $\alpha(0)=\alpha(2\pi)$). Thus, if $\omega$ is exact, then
$$
\int_{\alpha}\omega=0.
$$
But 
$$
\int_{\alpha}\omega=\int_0^{2\pi}\omega(\alpha(t)).\alpha'(t)dt=\int_0^{2\pi}(-sin(t),cos(t)).(-sin(t),cos(t))dt=2\pi
$$
Then $\omega$ is not exact.

Answer (score 0):

Another take on this (albeit obviously similar to the above solutions) is:

Note that $\omega|_{\delta B_1(0)}=-ydx+xdy$. but this is already its own Pullback onto $\delta B_1(0)$, as can be for example verified using polar coordinates.

Therefore $\omega|_{\delta B_1(0)}=\iota_{\delta B_1(0)}^*(\omega)=-ydx+xdy$.

Now obviously $-ydx+xdy\neq 0$ on $\delta B_1(0)$, because else $ydx=xdy$, wich cannot be because $dx$ and $dy$ are linearly independant and on $\delta B_1(0)$ $x$ and $y$ are not zero at the same time.

But then $-ydx+xdy$ is a nowhere vanishing top degree form on $\delta B_1(0)$, and therefore $\int_{\delta B_1(0)} -ydx+xdy\neq 0$. Actually $\iota_{\delta B_1(0)}^*\omega$ can be reckoned to be up to sign the "canonical" volume form of $\delta B_1(0)$, and therefore cant have Integral 0, but has the 1-volume of $\delta B_1(0)$, up to sign, as integral.

But if $\iota_{\delta B_1(0)}^*\omega$ was exact one would have $\iota_{\delta B_1(0)}^*\omega=d\omega'$ for some $\omega'$ on $\delta B_1(0)$, because $\delta B_1(0)$ is compact and without boundary, stokes theorem applies to $\iota_{\delta B_1(0)}^*\omega$ on $\delta B_1(0)$, yielding:

$\int_{\delta B_1(0)}\iota_{\delta B_1(0)}^* \omega=\int_{\delta B_1(0)}d\omega'=\int_{\delta\delta B_1(0)=\emptyset}\omega'=0$, contradiction to $\int_{\delta B_1(0)}\iota_{\delta B_1(0)}^*\omega\neq 0$ as established earlier.

But therefore $\iota_{\delta B_1(0)}^*\omega$ not exact.

But now suppose $\omega=d\omega''$, so $\omega$ exact, then because pullbacks commute with $d$ we have:

$\iota_{\delta B_1(0)}^* \omega=\iota_{\delta B_1(0)}^* d\omega''=d\iota_{\delta B_1(0)}^*\omega''=d\omega'$ for $\omega':=\iota_{\delta B_1(0)}^*\omega''$, so $\iota_{\delta B_1(0)}^*\omega$ would be exact after all, contradiciton.

The upshot of the argument is: Any differential form whose Pullback to some compact submanifold with positive dimension is a nonvanishing top degree form on the submanifold is not exact due to such a contradiction involving stokes.

Comment: And yet [another](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4605719/949989).