# Is every 2D vector field locally integrable up to a rescaling?

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, differential-forms, vector-fields, integrating-factor

Let $\Omega$ be a region of the plane (simply connected, say, if it matters), and $v(x,y)$ a smooth vector field on $\Omega$.

Does there always exist a scalar field $s:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ so that $sv$ is locally integrable: so that for every point $(x_0,y_0)\in\Omega$, in some neighborhood of that point,
$$s(x,y)v(x,y) = \nabla f(x,y)$$
for some $f:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$?

Equivalently, does there always exist an $s$ with $\nabla \times (sv) =0$?

EDIT: As pointed out below, we want $s$ not identically zero, as this is clearly a trivial solution. The below answer also gives a counterexample, though it seems to rely fundamentally on $v$ having a singularity of nontrivial index; is the claim true if we require $v$ to be nowhere-vanishing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may w.l.o.g. use the [musical isomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_isomorphism) to reformulate OP's question as follows:

> *Question:* Given a nowhere vanishing smooth one-form 
>   $$\omega~=~f\mathrm{d}x+ g\mathrm{d}y~\in~ \Omega^1(\mathbb{R}^2)\tag{1}$$ 
>   in the plane$^1$ $\mathbb{R}^2$, does there exist a **globally** defined smooth [integrating factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor)$^2$ $\lambda$ such that $\lambda \omega $ is an [exact one-form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_differential) $\mathrm{d}h$?

Answer: *No,* the existence of an integrating factor $\lambda$ is only guaranteed in **local** neighborhoods.

> *Counterexample:* Ref. 1 shows on p. 53 that the one-form 
>   $$\omega~=~f\mathrm{d}x+ g\mathrm{d}y ~=~y^3(1-y)^2 \mathrm{d}x+ (y^3-2(1-y)^2)\mathrm{d}y\tag{2}$$ 
>   has **no globally** defined smooth integrating factor $\lambda$.

*Indirect proof:* Assume that there exist $\lambda,h\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ such that $$\lambda\omega~=~\mathrm{d}h. \tag{3}$$ Restrict to the open strip $\Omega :=\mathbb{R}\times ]0,1[$. Then 
$$ \frac{1}{f}\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}~=~\lambda~=~\frac{1}{g}\frac{\partial h}{\partial y}, \qquad (x,y)~\in~\Omega. \tag{4}$$
Perform bi-smooth coordinate transformation: $\Omega \to \Omega$
$$ (\widetilde{x},\widetilde{y})~=~\left(x+\frac{1}{y^2}+\frac{1}{1-y},y\right)\qquad\Leftrightarrow \qquad (x,y)~=~\left(\widetilde{x}-\frac{1}{\widetilde{y}^2}-\frac{1}{1-\widetilde{y}},\widetilde{y}\right)  .\tag{5}$$
Conclude that $h$ does not depend on $\widetilde{y}$:
$$\frac{\partial h}{\partial \widetilde{y}}
 ~=~\frac{\partial y}{\partial \widetilde{y}}\frac{\partial h}{\partial y}+  \frac{\partial x}{\partial \widetilde{y}} \frac{\partial h}{\partial x} 
~\stackrel{(5)}{=}~\frac{\partial h}{\partial y}+ \left( \frac{2}{y^3}- \frac{1}{(1-y)^2} \right) \frac{\partial h}{\partial x}
~\stackrel{(2)}{=}~\frac{\partial h}{\partial y}- \frac{g}{f}   \frac{\partial h}{\partial x}
~\stackrel{(4)}{=}~0,\tag{6} $$
i.e. $h$ is only a function of $\widetilde{x}$. Hence $$\lambda ~\stackrel{(4)}{=}~\frac{h^{\prime}(\widetilde{x})}{f}.\tag{7}$$ This leads to the contradiction:
$$ 0~\neq~\lambda(x,y=1)~\stackrel{(7)}{=}~\lim_{y\to 0^+} \frac{h^{\prime}(\widetilde{x})}{f(x,y)}
~=~\lim_{\widetilde{x}\to \infty}\widetilde{x}^{3/2} h^{\prime}(\widetilde{x}),\tag{8} $$
vs.
$$ 0~\neq~\lambda(x,y=0)~\stackrel{(7)}{=}~\lim_{y\to 1^-} \frac{h^{\prime}(\widetilde{x})}{f(x,y)}
~=~\lim_{\widetilde{x}\to \infty}\widetilde{x}^{2} h^{\prime}(\widetilde{x}), \tag{9}$$
$\Box$

References:

1. J.B. Boyling, *Carathéodory's principle and the existence of global integrating factors,* [Commun. Math. Phys. 10 (1968) 52](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01654133). [Project Euclid](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.cmp/1103840983).

--

$^1$ We chose the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ as an example of a [contractible space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contractible_space). It is [easy](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/786837/11127) to come up with examples of [closed one-forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_and_exact_differential_forms) that are not exact in non-contractible spaces. (OP indirectly asks if it matters if the region is not [simply connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simply_connected_space)? Yes, it does!)

$^2$ An integrating factor $\lambda$ is by definition nowhere vanishing.

Comment: Ok, this answer (and the related discussion in the cited reference) is definitive. Integrability is only guaranteed locally, even for topologically simple domains. Thanks!

Comment: FYI, this answer has been cited in our upcoming paper "Weaving Geodesic Foliations" (preprint at https://www.dropbox.com/s/wh1dm4bfncchldy/weaving_polished.pdf?dl=0). Thanks again!

Comment: $\uparrow$ Thanks! :)

Answer (score 4):

If you take $s=0$ this is always so. Thats cheating, as you may agree. We could ask for $s$ to never be zero, or to not be zero unless $v$ is also zero.

With those restrictions it is false. Let $v= r\,e_\varphi$ on $\Bbb R^2$ in polar coordinates. If you integrate $sv$ along a circle of Radius $R$ centered around zero you will get
$$\int_0^{2\pi} R\,s(R\cos\varphi,R\sin\varphi)\,d\varphi.$$
Note that because we are not allowing $s$ to become zero on this circle, that the sign of the integrand must remain constant. For that reason this integral is never zero. However, if $sv=\nabla f$ then the integral of $sv$ around a closed curve must be zero. Since our domain $\Bbb R^2$ is contractible, the global question of whether or not there exists an $f$ with $\nabla f=sv$ is the same as the local question.

Comment: Your example is well-taken, however something still is not fully satisfactory here, because I can take $s = \frac{1}{r^2}$ and get a vector field that is integrable almost everywhere (although not, it is true, at $r=0$). So is the statement true if one restricts to $\bar\Omega = \Omega \setminus S$ for some (countable?) set of singularities $S$?

Comment: I think you want $s=1/r$. Around any point that is not zero there exists a neighbourhood on which you can define a smooth $s$ so that $sv$ is conservative on that neighbourhood. You may be looking for a counter-example where the points on which you cannot do this (which for this example is only zero) have non-zero measure.

Comment: "Around any point that is not zero there exists a neighbourhood on which you can define a smooth $s$ so that $sv$ is conservative on that neighbourhood" Do you have a sketch for how to prove this? Along integral curves of the perpendicular vector field to $v$ we have the ODE $$0 = \nabla \times (sv) \Rightarrow \nabla_{v^{\perp}} s = -s\nabla \times v.$$ But how do we find a compatible $\nabla_v s$?

Comment: My comment was about this specific example, not a general remark. For this specific example use $s=1/r$.

Comment: Ok. Is the claim true in general? I’ve looked at the Frobenius integrability theorem but not sure how to apply it here.

Comment: Comment to the answer (v1): The vector field $v=r\vec{e}_{\varphi}=(-y,x)$ is indeed smooth, but vanishes in the origin.

Answer (score 2):

As s.harp has pointed out this is not always possible, as illustrated by his example where the integral curves of $v$ swirl around some point. However it is always possible to find such a factor provided $v$ is non-zero. As you pointed out since the domain is simple connected it suffices to find $s$ such that $\nabla \times (sv) =0$, which is equivalent to 
$$ \partial_y(sv^1)-\partial_x(sv^2)=v^1\partial_ys-v^2\partial_xs+(\partial_yv^1-\partial_xv^2)s=0$$
which we write as
$$v^\perp\cdot\nabla s + (\partial_yv^1-\partial_xv^2)s=0$$

This is a linear transport equation for $s$, and can be solved by the method of characteristics. The characteristics are the integral curves of $v^\perp=(-v^2,v^1)$, and its easy to see we can solve it provided these curves don't loop around. So long as $v(x_0,y_0)\neq 0$ then certainly you can solve it in a neighbourhood of $(x_0,y_0)$, and I think probably you can even argue somehow that it can be solved globally provided $v$ is nowhere vanishing (or making some other statement ensuring the existence of a Cauchy surface for the integral curves of $v^\perp$) .

*Added in note*: For global existence it turns out that a stronger condition than nowhere-vanishing $v$ is needed. See  the comments below.

Comment: Comment to the answer (v3): A nowhere vanishing $v$ is not enough to guarantee the existence of a globally defined $s$, cf.  counterexample in my answer.

Comment: Ah thank-you, excellent example. It appears I was being naive to think that might be enough, as a plot of your vector field $v(x,y)=(y^3(1-y)^2,y^3-2(1-y)^2)$ easily illustates there is no Cauchy surface. I guess for global existence you need a much stronger constraint, such as ensuring that one component of $v$ is nowhere vanishing (or instead that there exists a fixed vector $n$ such that $n \cdot v$ is nowhere vanishing).