# Computing $\int_{S^{1} \times S^{1}} d\theta_{1} \wedge d\theta_{2}$

Tags: differential-topology, differential-forms

Let $S^{1} \times S^{1}$ be the torus embedded in $\mathbb{R}^{4}$. I want to compute

$\int_{S^{1} \times S^{1}} d\theta_{1} \wedge d\theta_{2}$

I believe this should be "essentially" $\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} d\theta_{1} d\theta_{2}= 4 \pi^{2}$. I mainly just wanted to see justification.

I've been reading about differential forms in Guillemin and Pollack, where I did a similar exercise, where I saw that for $$\omega = \frac{x dy - y dx}{x^2+y^2}$$, the pull-back allows under the map $h(t)=(\cos(t), \sin(t))$ allows us to see that ([see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/786837/show-that-the-form-w-is-closed-but-not-exact)):

$$\int_{S^{1}} \omega = \int^{2\pi}_{0} h^{*}\omega=2\pi$$

I feel like in this case, we have something similar with $$\omega_{i} = \frac{x_{i} dy_{i} - y_{i} dx_{i}}{x_{i}^2+y_{i}^2}$$ 
and considering $$\int_{S^{1} \times S^{1}} \omega_{1} \wedge \omega_{2}$$
in similar fashion change coordinates say by considering a map $H:(s,t) \mapsto (h(s), h(t))$ and considering the pull-back. Would this be a way to justify it?

Comment: Read the definition of the integral carefully and proceed step by step.

Comment: @CharlieFrohman, If they could do that then why would they be asking?

Comment: Yes, you're proceeding correctly. All you need at the end is Fubini's Theorem, to turn the double integral into the product of single integrals.

Comment: Thank you! So we pull back via $H$ to get $\int_{(0, 2\pi) \times (0, 2\pi)} d{\theta_{1}} \wedge d\theta_{2}$ and then apply Fubini's theorem?